# Can't get bootstrap working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I've been trying to connect bootstrap framework to my project by following this [documentation](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass) and I can't set it up for some reason.
Why is it?

**assets/stylesheets/application.scss**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";
 * 
 *= require bootstrap3-editable/bootstrap-editable
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

**assets/javascripts/application.js**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap3-editable/bootstrap-editable
//= require_tree .
```

**views/layouts/application.html.erb**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Greenbull</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>


  <div id="container">
    <div id="user_header">
      <% if current_user %>
        Logged in as <%= current_user.full_name %>
      <%= link_to "Log Out", logout_path("current"), method: 'delete' %><br />
      <p><%= link_to "My tasks", user_tasks_path(current_user) %>
      <% else %>
        <%= link_to "Sign Up", signup_path %> or
        <%= link_to 'Log In', login_path %>
      <% end %>
    </div>

  <% flash.each do |message_type, message| %>
   <div class="flash-<%= message_type %>"><%= message %></div>
  <% end %>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0'
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'bcrypt'
  gem 'pry'
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'bootstrap-x-editable-rails'
  gem 'bootstrap-sass'
end
```

I have installed bootstrap-sass 3.3.5.1, sass-rails 5.0.3.

Any help?

Comment: try like this instead of this assets/stylesheets/application.scss  rename to assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the instructions of the bootstrap-sass gem and follow their conventions https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass.

```
Import Bootstrap styles in app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:

// "bootstrap-sprockets" must be imported before "bootstrap" and "bootstrap/variables"
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```